# xsb "No procedure usermod" when predicate is already defined

Tags: prolog, xsb

So in my file I have

```
:- use_module(standard, datime/1).

today(Y, M, D) :-
    datime(datime(Y, M, D, _, _, _).
```

Running this directly in the command line gives

```
XSB Version 3.6. (Gazpatcho) of April 22, 2015
[x86-pc-windows; mode: optimal; engine: slg-wam; scheduling: local]
[Build date: 2015-04-22]

| ?- use_module(standard, datime/1).

yes
| ?- datime(datime(Y, M, D, _, _, _)).

Y = 2016
M = 5
D = 17

yes
```

But loading the file itself and running the function gives an error

```
| ?- [utils].
[Compiling .\utils]
[utils compiled, cpu time used: 0.0780 seconds]
[utils loaded]

yes
| ?- today(Y, M, D).
++Error[XSB/Runtime/P]: [Existence (No procedure usermod : today / 3 exists)] []
Forward Continuation...
... machine:xsb_backtrace/1  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\machine.xwam
... loader:load_pred1/1  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\loader.xwam
... loader:load_pred0/1  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\loader.xwam
... loader:load_pred/1  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\loader.xwam
... x_interp:_$call/1  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\x_interp.xwam
... x_interp:call_query/1  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\x_interp.xwam
... standard:call/1  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\standard.xwam
... standard:catch/3  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\standard.xwam
... x_interp:interpreter/0  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\x_interp.xwam
... loader:ll_code_call/3  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\loader.xwam
... standard:call/1  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\standard.xwam
... standard:catch/3  From C:\Program Files (x86)\XSB\syslib\standard.xwam
```

Any idea why this is the case and how to fix this? This happens for other predicates in the file as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code:

1. Your declaration of `today/3` is missing a closing `)`,
2. `today/3` isn't exported
3. `use_module/2` expects a list of symbols as second argument, alternatively use `import sym from mod`.

If you define your `utils.P` file as following

```
:- import datime/1 from standard.
:- export today/3.
today(Y, M, D) :- datime(datime(Y, M, D, _, _, _)).
```

you can use it in either of the following ways:

Import the predicate directly:

```
| ?- import today/3 from utils.

yes
| ?- today(Y,M,D).

Y = 2016
M = 5
D = 18
```

use a qualified name using `:`

```
| ?- utils:today(Y,M,D).

Y = 2016
M = 5
D = 18
```

loading the module directly

```
| ?- [utils].
[utils loaded]

| ?- today(Y,M,D).

Y = 2016
M = 5
D = 18
```

Comment: That worked! But does this mean that I have to `export` every single predicate I define within the module?

Comment: If you don't declare anything using `export` then everything is automatically exported. But this might be dangerous if you use overlapping names internally that you didn't mean to export.

Comment: So not using `export` wasn't the real issue, it's the lack of a closing bracket. Thanks! Well, I guess it's a stupid error on my part really.